# The RSA key container could not be opened

Tags: audience-manager, sites-9.6

We are using Tridio sites 9.6. I m getting errors while retrieving contacts

```
StaticAddressBook addressBook in StaticAddressBook.GetList(new UserContext("DR-SDL-DCMS1\\mtsuser"), new TcmUri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PublicationURI"]))
```

**MTSUser** is already added using

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "TridionRsaKeyContainer" "DR-SDL-DCMS1\mtsuser"
```

Below is the complete exception

```
[ConfigurationErrorsException: The RSA key container could not be opened.]
   System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.ThrowBetterException(Boolean keyMustExist) +169
   System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.GetCryptoServiceProvider(Boolean exportable, Boolean keyMustExist) +351
   System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.Decrypt(XmlNode encryptedNode) +81
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.ConfigurationEncryption.TraverseAndProcessChildren(Dictionary`2 protectedConfigurationProviders, XmlNode node) +418
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.ConfigurationEncryption.DecryptConfiguration(XmlDocument rawConfiguration) +186
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.Configuration.Reload() +374

[LocalizableConfigurationErrorsException: Loading of the configuration failed.]
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.Configuration.Reload() +858
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.Configuration..cctor() +196

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.Configuration' threw an exception.]
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.ServiceClient.ContentManagerClient.GetClient(UserContext userContext, AccessTokenData& userData) +168
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.ServiceClient.ContentManagerClient.LoadCurrentUser(UserContext userContext, String accessTokenDataXml) +369
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.UserContext..ctor(String trusteeName) +168
   Tridion.AudienceManagement.API.UserContext..ctor(String trusteeName) +42
   SubscriberDataAccess.GetAddressBooksFromPublication() in d:\TridionCustomPages\SubscriberReport\App_Code\SubscriberDataAccess.cs:307
   _default.BindValuesToList() in d:\TridionCustomPages\SubscriberReport\default.aspx.cs:359
   _default.DataBindControls() in d:\TridionCustomPages\SubscriberReport\default.aspx.cs:398
   _default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\TridionCustomPages\SubscriberReport\default.aspx.cs:38
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +90
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1533
```

Comment: @Velmurugan can u please help